# Matching the URL path with <a> attr('href') to dynamically update .active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i have my navbar code in a navbar.php file and the HTML looks like as follows :

```
<nav role="navigation" class="nav" >
      <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">
        Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.php">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.php">Products</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="active">product-1</li>
                <li>product-2</li>
                <li>product-3</li>
                <li>product-4</li>
                <li>product-5</li>
                <li>product-6</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

onpage load i am running a very simple Jquery snippet to run through all the `<a>` and check if thier href matches the url (actually end of the url eg. index.php )  in the browser .

So i have the following Jquery snippet :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

var _urlpath = $(location).attr('pathname');
            console.log(_urlpath);  // this does't print out the desired version , it prints `/lala-v1/about-us.php"`

        $('#menu > li').each(function(){
            var _str = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            console.log(_str); // these print out the desired output eg. index.php
            if(_str == _urlpath){
                console.log(_str + _urlpath);
            }
        });

});
```

checkout my comments and , my difficulty is getting the correct url path on the 2nd line of on Jquery . I went through [this](http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery) article and none of of the Jquery options i see are going to return the end part of the URL i see .

so what do i do ? i am stuck , is there a way around this in JS/Jquery .

I am new to both these feilds , so i would appreciate any help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var _urlpath = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
// or: $(location).attr('pathname').split('/').pop();
```

Comment: @devgon , thanks genious , this worked , BTW , i taught i would need some kind of a regex , but nvm now.

Comment: A regex would probably be your best bet if you are including params, e.g.: /lala-v1/about-us.php?myVar=2

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` , it will return the absolute path, not the string that has been set for the attribute .

Comparing filenames may fail, there may be files with equal names in different directories.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#menu > li').each(function(){
            var _str = $(this).find('a').prop('href');

            if(_str == location.href){
                $(this).css('background','red');
            }
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">
        Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">This is the current page, should be highlighted by jquery</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="active">product-1</li>
                <li>product-2</li>
                <li>product-3</li>
                <li>product-4</li>
                <li>product-5</li>
                <li>product-6</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: correction: It works also in IE, but not with the code-snippet(IE returns here not the desired value for `location.href`) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/hr9ojrwc/)(works in IE)

Comment: i have the following snippet http://chopapp.com/#lkff6vcp , it works now , but is it cross browser ?

Comment: `location.href` (which also applies to links) is available since the first JS-version, it should be available in any browser

Comment: thanks for the tip ;) btw , wht is a Dr doing on SO ?

Comment: I'm not a real Dr.  (in my hometown a "Molle" is a beer)

Answer (score 0):

The values won't match, since `/lala-v1/about-us.php !== about-us.html`, plus you're serving pages with ".php" and links are all ".html". You can use this to get the correct value: `window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();`

Comment: corrected the url links , sorry abt the confusion .